# How to test Pass statement in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, overriding

I have quite complex system with python 2.7. Often in subclasses I need to override methods of parent class with just 'pass' like:

```
class Parent():
    def some_method(self, data):
       # do something to data here
       ....

class Child(Parent):
   def some_method(self, data):
       # Do not touch data, it should remain unchanged
       pass
```

So my question: is there a way to test that method is overridden with a 'pass' statement? I mean an abstract test, given that it doesn't know anything about 'data': all it has is Child class, method name and that's it.
Of course, I can test that after running some_method data is not changed, but given the complexity of the system I have, there are too many places to check if something was affected, so I'm looking for an abstract solution.

**UPD** yes, this design is way far from perfect, I know, but can't help it, it's a legacy issue, so let's please leave the system design discussion aside except for one note: *don't design your systems like this:)*

Comment: You can only test for the absence of the original behaviour..

Comment: But to be honest, it sounds like your system is in serious need of refactoring instead.

Comment: How have you ended up with this design? I suspect an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Comment: Well, the design and refactoring is a separate topic:) , but for this question let's just presume, that the system should stay AS-IS. I need to find the best solution for writing test to specified problem

Comment: You have already found the *only* solution, short of introspection to check that the specific code implementation is just `pass` - the fact that that's rather awkward is *telling you that you need to fix the design*.

Comment: In my case, I overrode a `save()` method. This method returned an object. `assert MyClass().save(random_variable='random text') is None` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I've come so far is (not totally abstract, but abstract enough for my case):

In test case call the subclass method intentionally passing it wrong-typed values, like None in my case:

```
def test_method_pass_statement(self):
    test_class = Child()
    try:
        # If method isn't overridden, this should raise exception
        # but check for your case if None doesn't raise exception
        test_class.some_method(None)
    except <Exception_type>:
        # Customise error and message the way you want
        raise
```

If the method is overridden with pass, it would consume whatever you pass it, given the number of arguments is correct.

Comment: 1. Bare `except` is very bad practice, even in testing. 2. What if the parent class handles `None` as an input *without* raising an error?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, both points are perfectly valid. But I'm putting here just the boilerplate for the idea how it could be tested, given that it would tailored to particular cases.